# Upgrade to 5.9.0 - 'From' address for e-mail confirmations has changed

Tags: civimail

Following our upgrade to CiviCRM 5.9.0, the 'from' address for event registration confirmations has changed to "7306@civi.acenterprises.org.uk"

It should be ""Ian Foster" " - and this is what still appears in the list of 'From' addresses in CiviCRM settings.

I've looked at contact ID 7306, in case it is a contact ID, and they have no significance in our system.

Baffled!  Any thoughts? Thank you.

Comment: Forgot to say - we are on Drupal 7.60 as CRM

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is now fixed and should be part of next release hopefully. You may wait for next release or apply patch manually from [here](https://github.com/civicrm/civicrm-core/pull/13407/files).

Comment: Thanks - I always search on here before posting but somehow missed the pre-existing post :)

Answer (score 1):

There has been a bug in sending confirmation receipts for renewals of memberships in 5.8.2 and 5.9.0:

[Confirmation receipt sent from strange sender address](https://civicrm.stackexchange.com/questions/27905/confirmation-receipt-sent-from-strange-sender-address)

Apparently, instead of setting the sender name, the table index of the sender name was set instead. It might be the case that the same bug is showing up for event registration confirmations as well.

You mention that 7306 is not the id of "Ian Foster" - but maybe it is some other kind of index value?